# Convert datetime string to unix timestamp in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, iso8601

Azure Resource Manager templates have functions for creating and converting ISO 8601 formatted timestamps.  Unfortunately, Key Vault secret expiration attribute requires seconds since Unix epoch.  How can I generate an arbitrary date time as seconds since Unix epoch in an ARM template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think you can (at least there is no shortcut for that), easier to generate this outside of the template and pass it to the template as a parameter

Comment: is correct, no easy way to do this today... you *could* do some math yourself, and approximate it, but I think it would be hard to get precise...

Comment: and no point really, this can be done with a oneliner outside of the template and just pass it in, alternatively you can create an http endpoint that does the calculations based on something and query that endpoint as an arm template. again, another alternative would be using the deploymentScripts resource(s)

Comment: I think outside is better - you can do *anything* in a template with a deploymentScript, but that's not a path we'd recommend for something this lightweight